# ChartJS bar graph to show different width for different graph

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2, stacked-bar-chart

I have created a Marimekko chart using chartjs and react , but i have a problem in assigning different width for each stack bar . I tried barPercentage,categoryPercentage but nothing works .
below is my chart , as seen every bar has same width , i want to change it to have 40% width for the first stackbar which is <7.5Oz. , 20% for the second which is 7.5 - 12.5 Oz., 10% for the third 12.5 - 17.5 Oz. , 30% for the fourth which is 17.5 + Oz..
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTm2s.png)

but whatever i try it is just showing the same width for all the bars

[MariMekko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uq5j.png)

above is currently my graph ,
and below is my code .

Marimekko/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

function MerimekkoChart() {
  const data = {
    labels: ["<7.5 Oz.", "7.5-12.5 Oz.", "12.5-17.5 Oz.", "17.5+ Oz."],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "<$3.5",
        data: [35, 49, 17, 0],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)",
        stack: "stack1",
        barPercentage: 1.09,
        categoryPercentage: 0.9,
      },
      {
        label: "$3.5-$4.5",
        data: [34, 47, 69, 66],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.7)",
        stack: "stack1",
        barPercentage: 1.09,
        categoryPercentage: 0.9,
      },
      {
        label: "$4.5+",
        data: [31, 4, 14, 34],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)",
        stack: "stack1",
        barPercentage: 1.09,
        categoryPercentage: 0.9,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "center",
        align: "center",
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
        },
        formatter: (value) => (value !== 0 ? value : ""),
        color: "#000", // Set the color for the data labels
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          categoryPercentage: 1,
          barPercentage: 0.7,
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          display: false,
          stacked: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  return <Bar data={data} options={options} />;
}

export default MerimekkoChart;`
```

and below is code for component index.js

```
// @mui material components
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import MDBox from "components/MDBox";
import DashboardNavbar from "examples/Navbars/DashboardNavbar";
import DashboardLayout from "examples/LayoutContainers/DashboardLayout";
import Merimekko from "examples/Cards/Mermekko";
import stack2BarChartData from "layouts/StackedChart2Menu/data/Stack2BarChartData";
import OrdersOverview from "layouts/dashboard/components/OrdersOverview";
import MDTypography from "../../components/MDTypography";

function StackedChart2Menu() {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      <DashboardNavbar />
      <MDBox py={5}>
        <MDBox>
          <MDBox
            mx={2}
            mt={-3}
            py={3}
            px={2}
            variant="gradient"
            bgColor="info"
            borderRadius="lg"
            coloredShadow="info"
          >
            <MDTypography variant="h6" color="white">
              Distribution
            </MDTypography>
          </MDBox>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={12}
              md={6}
              lg={8}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                marginTop: "15px",
                WebkitBoxShadow:
                  "0rem 0.25rem 0.375rem -0.0625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0rem 0.125rem 0.25rem -0.0625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
                marginLeft: "36px",
                marginRight: "20px",
              }}
            >
              <Merimekko color="info" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={1}
              md={1}
              lg={3.6}
              style={{ width: "20px", marginLeft: "-30px", marginTop: "-10px" }}
            >
              <OrdersOverview />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </MDBox>
      </MDBox>
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
}

export default StackedChart2Menu;`
```

Above is my code that i used to get , the expectation here is to get different width for different stack bars , and to make it look like below [Expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umKHq.png)

it should have value% inside the stack, some value should be written on top of each stack and different width needs to be assigned to each of stack bars